# react-router-dom repite elemento div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy aprendiendo React y tengo un problema a la hora de usar react-router-dom para usar urls dinámicas. Pretendo tener un indice de noticias y que cuando hagas click en una de ellas, te lleve a su url. Esto me funciona bien, el problema es que me sigue renderizando los div de todos los elementos que hay dentro del array.

```
class App extends Component {

state = {
    data: []
};

async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/');
    const data = await res.json();
    this.setState({data});

}


render(){

    return (

    <div className="col-md-12">
        <Router>
            <Route path='/all-news' render={(props) => <AllNews data={this.state.data} /> } />
        </Router>
        {
            this.state.data.map((items, i) => {
            return ( 
                <div key={i}>
                    <Router>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path={items.baseUrl} render={() => <NewsWag1Mag title={items.title} content={items.content} /> } />

                        </Switch>
                    </Router>
                </div>
                )  
            })
        }
    </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: lo que intentas hacer es que al seleccionar un ítem, no salga mas la lista con todos los elegibles?

Comment: Exacto, es que siguen saliendo los divs, salen vacíos pero siguen apareciendo, y eso es lo que no quiero porque si no aparecerán tantos divs como elementos tenga el array.

Comment: dejo una imagen para ilustrar mejor el problema. https://imgur.com/nkJamZj @nauseantparrot